# Syntax to insert values in MS SQL SERVER

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

I thought of immersing myself with database projects so I got into MS SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT and got stuck in a part where my friend insert a statement where the code's logic should insert values to the table(dbo.course) but my friend left it and I have no idea how it works.. now I check the table.. It's still left blank..

This is it right here

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class main {

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;" + 
        "databaseName=database_sample;integratedSecurity=true"; 

// Database credentials
/*
 * static final String USER = "root"; static final String PASS = "root";
 */


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String course_code = null, course_desc = null, course_chair = null;

    try {
        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.print("\nConnecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        /*
         * PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE databasename");
         * int result = ps.executeUpdate();
         */
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");

        // STEP 4: Ask for user input
        System.out.print("Enter course code: ");
        course_code = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter course description: ");
        course_desc = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter course chair: ");
        course_chair = scn.nextLine();

        // STEP 5: Execute query
        System.out.print("\nInserting records into table...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();


        String sql = "INSERT INTO course (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)" +
                "VALUES ('\"+course_code+\"','\"+course_desc+\"','\"+course_chair+\"')"; /*
                         * "INSERT INTO course " + "VALUES (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)";
                         */


        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
        }
        try {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for your patronage!");
  }
```

}

I repeat it doesn't insert values.. I look at the table(dbo.course).. Nothings there

Comment: I dont know java, but still I think you are missing a statement where you actually execute the insert statement. It looks like you only print it, not execute it

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something with the sql. Currently ist just a `String` and nothing else is done with it.
 You need to pass the query to the statement and trigger its execution.

```
     // STEP 5: Execute query
     System.out.print("\nInserting records into table...");
     stmt = conn.createStatement();

     String sql = "INSERT INTO course (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)" +
                  "VALUES ('\"+course_code+\"','\"+course_desc+\"','\"+course_chair+\"')";

     stmt.executeQuery(sql); // <--- add this
     System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
```

Also change your `finally` block.
 There is a typo (you close `conn` twice)
and to make sure that both (`stmt` and `conn`) are really closed, they have to be in a cascaded `finally` block (there could still be a `RuntimeException` in the first close operation, which would prevent the closing of the 2nd resource).

```
    } finally {
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
        } finally {
           try {
              if(conn != null)
                  conn.close();
           } catch(SQLException se) {
                 se.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }
```

An alternate solution for the `finally` block would be to use a `try with resource` for both of them. Read up on it.

Comment: Also his query won't execute anyway. There is no space between the closing parentheses and VALUES

Comment: @juice That is perfectly ok to do it like that. There is no need for a space between the closing bracket of the columns list and the `values(`

Comment: @GuidoG It is absolutely not okay. This isn't SSMS. It's Java. That is all one line and will execute as such `INSERT INTO course (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)VALUES ('\"+course_code+\"','\"+course_desc+\"','\"+course_chair+\"')`

Comment: @juice I dont know java, but do I understand correct that the command that will be send to the database will look like `INSERT INTO course (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)VALUES (...` ? If so, then I dont see the problem. Sql-Server will understand this

Comment: But as I said, I dont know java so please correct me if I did not understand it correct